# Emacs Auctex compile error: "Use M-x make-directory RET RET to create the directory and its parents"

Tags: emacs, latex, auctex

I am running emacs 23.3.1 on ubuntu 12.04 with auctex 11.86.  Whenever I go to compile a latex document (using <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>), if there are no errors, everything compiles just fine.  However, if there are any errors it will tell me to use <kbd>C-`</kbd> to view errors, if I do so, I get this error message

> Use M-x make-directory RET RET to create the directory and its parents

and it goes away after a couple seconds.  Then it takes me to another screen that explains the error in the latex code.  However, now I cannot simply do <kbd>C-x 1</kbd> to get back to the latex code.  I have to <kbd>C-x C-c</kbd> and restart emacs.

This is my `.emacs` file

```lisp
(setq backup-by-copying t
      backup-directory-alist '(("." . "~/.emacsBkups"))
      delete-old-versions t
      kept-new-versions 5
      kept-old-versions 2
      version-control t)


(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)

;;(require 'ess-site)
;;(ess-toggle-underscore nil)
(require 'whitespace)
(setq whitespace-style '(lines-tail face))

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'whitespace-mode)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'whitespace-mode)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'whitespace-mode)

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.h\\'" . c++-mode))
(c-set-offset (quote cpp-macro) 0 nil)



(setq TeX-view-program-list '(("Evince" "evince --page-index=%(outpage) %o")))
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "Evince")))
```

Comment: AUCTeX 12.82? O.o  The last stable version is 11.87, where did you get AUCTeX?

Comment: Oh Wait...I just went back and checked and it says 11.86....not sure what I originally saw.  I made the edit.

Comment: Has your document spaces in its path?

Comment: my document name is WNS_poster.tex  I tried it without the underscore and it still gives me the error

Comment: Put this in your `.emacs`: `(setq LaTeX-command-style '(("" "%(PDF)%(latex) -file-line-error %S%(PDFout)")))`, restart Emacs and let us knows whether this works.

Comment: That worked!  Can you explain what that line of code is doing?  I will mark this as solved.

Comment: Consider updating Emacs and AUCTeX.  23.3.1 and 11.86 respectively are both really old, and lack many modern features.  I don't know about AUCTeX, but for Emacs there is a PPA which provides the latest 24.3 release.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes AUCTeX gets confused parsing the log of (La)TeX compilation and isn't able to guess the correct line raising the error. In some cases AUCTeX issues an obscure message "Error occured after last TeX file closed", when there are unbalanced parentheses, in your case it suggests you to create a new directory. To help AUCTeX finding the correct line raising the error you can add the `-file-line-error` option to `latex` or `pdflatex` by customizing the variable `LaTeX-command-style`. To do this add the following code to your `.emacs`:

```lisp
(setq LaTeX-command-style '(("" "%(PDF)%(latex) -file-line-error %S%(PDFout)")))
```

See also the [AUCTeX FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#FAQ):

> **8.** Why does `TeX-next-error` (<kbd>C-c `</kbd>) fail?
>
> When writing the log file, TeX puts information related to a file,
>   including error messages, between a pair of parentheses. AUCTeX
>   determines the file where the error happened by parsing the log file
>   and counting the parentheses. This can fail when there are other,
>   unbalanced parentheses present.
>
> As a workaround you can activate so-called file:line:error messages
>   for the log file. (Those are are easier to parse, but may lack some
>   details.) Either you do this in the configuration of your TeX system
>   (consult its manual to see where this is) or you add a command line
>   switch to the (la)tex call, e.g. by customizing `LaTeX-command-style` or
>   `TeX-command-list`.

Comment: Hello. I am using emacs 21.3 and had the 'Use C-u M-x make-directory RET RET to create directory and its parents' message and white textboard issue while opening a file in python mode. It turned out that the issue is related to the file path, as in the case of this question. More in the detail, I was opening files stored in a directory named 'Téléchargements', where the french accented e letter looks to cause the issue. Moving away the files solved the issue.